# .NET Framework Cipher Suites Azure and older Windows OS's

Tags: azure, ssl, windows-7, tls1.2, tls1.3

After a pen test I have to implement a more strict Azure policy on the Web server.

As a result, client PC's running older versions of Windows, i.e., Vista and Windows 7, can no longer establish a TLS/SSL connection using .NET Framework 4.8. I need to have a secure policy whilst allowing older Windows OS's to connect.

I have checked the supported Cipher Suites for Windows 7 and one of the supported Cipher Suite (I am only focussing on one for the sake of simplicity) is:

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256

Whereas Azure supports

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

It appears that the Cipher names have to be an exact match.

Is the Elliptic Curve P256 just a variant of TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA or is it completely different?

Is there another approach I should adopt or am I trying to do the impossible?

I tried configuring Azure with the non Elliptic Curve variants but they were not available.

I am unable to modify the Windows machines that are attempting to connect to Azure.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7) Windows 7 and more modern versions of windows have a large number of supported ciphersuites for TLS1.2 in common.